# Installation & loading of Phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have watched this tutorial about PHPmailer on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtNraQxUTM0&t=1s

And when I run '**composer require phpmailer/phpmailer**' I get this error: **'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

How do I fix the issue? Thank you!

Comment: Have you installed composer?

Comment: You need to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) before using the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install composer first.
[download and install composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Than you will able to find the command.

```
Php composer --help
```